# What are the consumers for state store changelog topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology using the processor api which updates a state store, configured with replication factor of 3, acks=ALL

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: products-source (topics: [products])
      --> products-processor
    Processor: products-processor (stores: [products-store])
      --> enriched-products-sink
      <-- products-source
    Sink: enriched-products-sink (topic: enriched.products)
      <-- products-processor
```

My monitoring shows me very little lag for the source topic (< 100 records), however there is significant lag on the changelog topic backing the store, to the order of millions of records.

I'm trying to figure out the root cause of the lag on this changelog topic, as I'm not making any external requests in this processor. There are calls to rocksdb state stores, but these data stores are all local and should be fast in retrieving.

My question is what exactly is the consumer of this change log topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consumer of the changelog topics is the restore consumer. The restore consumer is a Kafka consumer that is build into Kafka Streams. In contrast to the main consumer that reads records from the source topic, the restore consumer is responsible for restoring the local state stores from the changelog topics in case the local state is not existent or out-of-date. Basically, it ensures that the local state stores recover after a failure. The second purpose of restore consumers is to keep [stand-by tasks](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/architecture.html#streams_architecture_recovery) up-to-date.

Each stream thread in a Kafka Streams client has one restore consumer. The restore consumer is not a member of a consumer group and Kafka Streams assigns changelog topics manually to restore consumer. The offsets of restore consumers are not managed in the consumer offset topic `__consumer_offsets` as the offsets of the main consumer but in a file in the state store directory of a Kafka Streams client.

Comment: Additional question: should I care about this? Also why is this lag reported in the consumer group of Kafka-streams application?

Comment: The lag of the restore consumer helps you monitoring the restoration process after a rebalancing and how up-to-date your stand-by tasks are.

Comment: Would you have a reference to confluent documentation?

Comment: I am not sure what documentation you are looking for.

Comment: Where could we find the spec that says how offset are managed for the restore consumer.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are looking for. The file that contains the offsets for the restore consumer is called checkpoint file. The checkpoint file is not public facing, so there is no documentation. You can look into the code, though: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/OffsetCheckpoint.java